# Retrieve data from Custom settings

Tags: customsetting, dynamic

Is there a way to retrieve data from custom settings using getAll() on the name of the custom setting that is passed dynamically?
Eg : If I pass CS1__c as custom setting name -> it should give data of CS1
If I pass CS2__c as custom setting name -> it should give data of CS2 so on

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are these two different custom setting objects?  are they essentially the same but with different data in them?

Comment: Those are two different custom setting objects

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a Salesforce magic method that will do that for your.  Your best option I think is to build your own method using Database.query. At the end of the day a custom setting is an object which you can query. So you will have something like :

```
String objectName = 'CS1__c';
List<SObject> records = Database.query('SELECT ID FROM '+objectName);
```

The only thing you will need to do is to get dynamically all the fields of the selected custom setting using [Schema.getGlobalDescribe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_schema.htm).